# op_bad_signer error when adding sha256 hash signer on Stellar private network

Tags: multi-sig, private-network

I created a Stellar Private Network using the installation instructions from https://github.com/stellar/packages#sdf---packages. Everything worked well.

But when I try to use sha256 hash for multi-sig, it doesn't work. I get the error `op_bad_signer`.

This hash can be used on Testnet. `49bd3b8bc1cde1b78640e14ce5fdc2c982ce88139c2e3a473e270d46900bcfb8`

Things I have tried that have failed:

1. Create js-stellar-sdk to submit transaction.
2. Send XDR envelope directly to stellar-core.
3. Installed Stellar laboratory on my Stellar Private Network tried SetOptions.

Do I need to set up something to enable this feature?

Comment: Can you post your transaction in XDR format?

Comment: "extras": {
      "envelope_xdr": "AAAAALHG+wCSBnrRvXqbsZ7Y9Uhz2W5AVaZgAmzuXlmbTRHFAAAAZAAAU34AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAACSb07i8HN4beGQOFM5f3CyYLOiBOcLjpHPicNRpALz7gAAAABAAAAAAAAAAGbTRHFAAAAQIlkVga0KhrDmLVXpDeBEcamniLRblTD20Z70w3y+bRe0kzxGZ0Dtifq4jurhD8TE4+Ox2NltvI9L7ebg36Y0gk=",
      "result_codes": {
        "transaction": "tx_failed",
        "operations": [
          "op_bad_signer"
        ]
      },
      "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAF////+AAAAAA="
    }

Comment: var crypto = require('crypto');
var genHash = key => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(key).digest('hex');

genHash('dfdsfsfsffsdfdsfdsfdsfdsdsfsd8')  => '49bd3b8bc1cde1b78640e14ce5fdc2c982ce88139c2e3a473e270d46900bcfb8'

Comment: OK, so you're saying that this works on testnet but doesn't work in your private network? You you link to the transaction that succeeded in testnet?

Comment: I create new account and SetOptions with sha256Hash on testnet.

https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/ec69c7ae0c5a5cf4f712ecfb370e8af1520612f3bf9501a20f205dcec0f9411f

Comment: Can you confirm you are running the latest version of stellar-core in your private network?

Comment: Not latest version.
stellar-core 9.1.0 (a278e95978bdac6d1015d82f4859dad780e752d3)

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions by myself. After create Stellar Private Network, We must execute command to upgrade protocolversion to 9.

$ stellar-core -c 'upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=2018-01-31T20:00:00Z&protocolversion=9'